# Reference request: $n$-edge-coloring bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ such that monochromatic parts are isomorphic

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I am finding references for the following problem:

> We call a $n\times n$ 0-1 matrix *permutation* if there are exactly one $1$ in each row/column.
>   Suppose $A$ is a 0-1 matrix of size $n\times n$ in which there are exactly $n$ $1$s.
>
> **Conjecture.** There exist permutations $P_i,Q_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n P_iAQ_i = J$, where $J$ denotes the "all-$1$" matrix.

I am *sure* that we have a famous similar conjecture on non-bipartite graphs, i.e., $K_n$, in which we only consider the case that monochromatic parts are trees.
But I just cannot recall its name...

---

**Update.** (Mar 21, 2019) The name I forgot is *Ringel's Conjecture*.

Comment: For n=6 and A having the six ones be in the upper left corner (I+j < 3), I would like to see the six arrangements of A adding up to J.  Gerhard "Not Sure If It's Possible" Paseman, 2019.03.20.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman (a a b) (a c c) (b c b) (a a a) (b b b) (c c c)    (Write it as a 3x6 matrix and naturally construct a 6x6 one)